# Android: Text stretches to button?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

Is there a way this could be done? The functionality should be like an image which stretches and compresses with the change of dimension. I just don't want results like "tex.." on buttons.

If this is not possible in the XML, can you do it in programmaticly using Java? I formatted text to fit buttons perfectly, but when I tried it on a smaller device (even using "sp" units) the text couldn't fit the buttons.

What I tried is multiplying the text size by the ratio of the devices' screen widths, but it overshot with the results...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know about android. But for swing you can use layouts and the method setBounds(). Could that help?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Fiddle with these settings and you would be on your way.
The android:padding attribute sets the distance between the the view and it's internal contents.
You can fiddle with the value of padding so as to suite your requirements.

EDIT
[image: Screenshot]
Even Long text correctly fits into the button, you might also compare the first button with the second & third buttons, to appreciate the difference, if that was what you wanted.

Comment: Almost! While it does work in cases where the text comes short, it still doesn't compress it when it's too long, and limiting the line count doesn't seem to affect it, while setting it to single line only causes truncation. Also, I'm using GridLayout, so I can't use layout_width/height without messing it up.

Comment: Yeah, so a single line would of course truncate the text, so as to fit into a single line. I've not really had the opportunity to fiddle with GridLayout, so probably I'm not an expert to comment on it. Also, if we are sure that it's working on a normal layout, probably you have to read more about GridLayout and the way you would want to deal with it.